# infinite nested for loop in MIPS

Tags: for-loop, mips

So I've trying for quite awhile to debug this after I finish coding this bubble sort code to MIPS and I can't seem to pin point what the problem  might be with my logic. Note this is only a snippet. If you feel like some parts of missing, that is because I'm dealing with each part of the program individually. Assume that I already have an unsorted array filled with 12 numbers that I must sort.

I'm using mars_4.5 to check my output.

High-Level Code:

```
// arr[i] will be in the correct spot after every iteration
for (int i = n-1; i > 0; i--)   
   for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)  // Put arr[j] and arr[j+1] in order
       if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) // If they are out of order, swap them
       { 
          int tmp = arr[j];
          arr[j] = arr[j+1];
          arr[j+1] = tmp;
       }
```

Important information:

```
    # $s1 = n  size of the array
    # $s2 = i  outer loop counter
    # $s3 = j  inner loop counter.
    # $s5 is the address of the size (= 12)
    # $s0 is the starting address of the array
```

Edit: The MIPS code is working now.

MIPS Code:

```
  lw $s1, 0($s5)   # Load the size of the array into $s1.
  addi $s2, $s1, -1 # Perform the initialization i = n - 1

  For1: # outer for loop
     bltz $s2, Exit # Checks if i < 0. If true, exit out of the outer for loop.
     add   $s3, $zero, $zero  # sets j to zero after each iteration of the inner loop.
     j For2 # executes the nested for loop.
     Update1: 
           addi $s2, $s2, -1 #i--
           j For1 # exceute back to the outer for loop.
  For2: # inner for loop   
     slt $t0, $s3, $s2
     bne $t0, 1, Update1 # If the inner loop fails, go back to outer loop 
     sll $t3, $s3, 2
     add $t3, $s0, $t3
     lw  $t1, 0($t3) # $t1 = arr[j]
     lw  $t2, 4($t3) # $t2 = arr[j + 1]
     slt $t0, $t2, $t1
     bne $t0, 1, Update2 # if the conditional fails
     sw $t2, 0($t3) # store contents of $arr[j + 1] into arr[j]
     sw $t1, 4($t3) # store contents of $arr[j] into arr[j + 1]     
     Update2: 
           addi $s3, $s3, 1 # j++
           j For2 
  Exit:
```

Every time I run the assembler in mars, there is no output for a very long time. Now I know that bubble sort is very inefficient when it comes to large arrays but this is only 12 elements. So my guess is something is wrong with the nested for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to leave spaces for delay slots after jump and branch instructions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a beginner when it comes to MIPS. What do you mean by delay slots?

Comment: MIPS use pipeline. While one command is executed, next one is read. To avoid waisting the efforts spent on reading the next command, this next command gets executed even if you branch. The slot containing such command (right next to the jump/branch instruction) is called "delay slot". A command in the delay slot executes whether you branch or not. There are also some limitations on what you can put into the delay slot - for example, you cannot put another branch command into there.

Comment: Alright I was to figure what was causing the infinite loop and was able to print out the array but it wasn't sorted so I guess I need to dig further. I've updated my MIPS code. hardly anything has changed except for what was causing the infinite loop.

Comment: @PineForestRanch: MARS by default doesn't simulate delay slots. They can be enabled in the settings menu, but the setting is off by default.

Comment: @Michael: Very interesting. I've never heard of MARS. What's the purpose of this MARS?

Comment: It's a MIPS simulator, commonly used at universities / colleges to allow students to run simple MIPS assembly programs that they write for various courses. The OP mentioned that he is using it.